# SSIS xlsx For Each File enumerator is empty to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a number of `.xlsx` files in a folder I wish the package to loop through and load. It loads the first one fine (the original you link), but I keep getting the error.

For each file, the enumerator is empty

I have even tried in the Foreach loop editor - collection set the Files of Wild. Wild to see if work, and the same error occur.

All Excel files have the same sheet name `Data` columns etc. I am loading the data into SQL Server. The variable path is correct.

Please help.

Comment: There could be so many reason, but we're lacking any information to help you here. We can't see you're SSIS package, or access your files, so you need to give us all the details about it and the files.

Comment: solved, folder permission, why or why cant ssis give proper error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The issue was folder permission. I did a test to local machine instead and it worked.

Used `c:\`  instead of `p:\`